# Crash on iOS 8 when dispatch_group_wait() return because of timeout

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

I have two operations fetching a value. I only care about the sum both values. And I don't care about the value at all if it takes too long.

So I thought it would be an easy task for GCD using groups. Unfortunately, the below code only works fine on iOS 9. Each time I have no matching calls of `dispatch_group_enter()`/`dispatch_group_leave()` I get a crash.

The documentation states clearly that I have to match both call. But when I use a timeout on `dispatch_group_wait()`, it is impossible to have the same amount of leave calls as enter calls; that is the whole point of specifying a timeout.

So is this a known bug in iOS 8? Am I doing something wrong? Is there another solution to my initial problem that works on iOS 8 as well?

**EDIT: Actually we can boil it down to this:**

```
var sync_group: dispatch_group_t = dispatch_group_create();
dispatch_group_enter(sync_group);
let maxWait = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(60 * NSEC_PER_SEC))
let result = dispatch_group_wait(sync_group, maxWait)

sync_group = dispatch_group_create();
```

Works as expected on iOS 9 but does crash on iOS 8 on the last line because the old dispatch_group_t instance can not be release. Any easy workarounds?

**EDIT 2: Turns out it is broken on iOS 9.0 too. It only works as as it should in iOS 9.1+.**

---

Original Code:

```
let qualityOfServiceClass = QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND
let backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(qualityOfServiceClass, 0)
dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, {

    /* We want this method to block until the network code succeeded. */
    let sync_group: dispatch_group_t = dispatch_group_create();

    /* Start async operation 1. */
    dispatch_group_enter(sync_group);
    self.someAsyncOperation1({(value: Int, finalValue: Bool) in
        if (finalValue) {
            valOp1 = value
            dispatch_group_leave(sync_group);
        }
    })

    /* Start async operation 2. */
    dispatch_group_enter(sync_group);
    self.someAsyncOperation2({(value: Int, finalValue: Bool) in
        if (finalValue) {
            valOp2 = value
            dispatch_group_leave(sync_group)
        }
    })

    /* Block current thread until all leaves were called. If it takes more then 60 sec we don't care and let go. */
    let maxWait = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(60 * NSEC_PER_SEC))
    let result = dispatch_group_wait(sync_group, maxWait)
    if (result > 0) {
       /* This will result in a crash when we leave the scope: SIGTRAP in dispatch_semaphore_dispose */            
       return
    }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        let newValue = valOp1 + valOp2
        self.lastKnownNotificationCombinedCounter = newValue
        success(newValue)
    })
})
```

The actual crash loops like that:

```
Exception Type:  SIGTRAP
Exception Codes: #0 at 0x3958a2a4

Thread 2 Crashed:
0   libdispatch.dylib                    0x3958a2a4 _dispatch_semaphore_dispose$VARIANT$mp + 48
1   libdispatch.dylib                    0x3958b491 _dispatch_dispose$VARIANT$mp + 30
2   libdispatch.dylib                    0x3957ea8f -[OS_dispatch_object _xref_dispose] + 44
3   myApp                                0x00176a24 block_destroy_helper67 + 354
4   myApp                                0x00176ab8 0x2e000 + 1346232
5   myApp                                0x00178334 0x2e000 + 1352500
6   libsystem_blocks.dylib               0x395d3adb _Block_release + 216
7   Foundation                           0x2c4143b9 -[NSBlockOperation dealloc] + 58
8   libobjc.A.dylib                      0x39036d57 objc_object::sidetable_release(bool) + 164
9   libobjc.A.dylib                      0x390371a9 (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 402
10  libdispatch.dylib                    0x39589423 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 1176
11  libdispatch.dylib                    0x3958a1fb _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 104
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x396fae25 _pthread_wqthread + 666
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x396fab78 start_wqthread + 6
```

Comment: Did your someAsyncOperation1 or someAsyncOperation2 dispatch operation on backgroundQueue?

Comment: It is actually a ThirdParty component, so I'm not sure. Does it make a difference and if so, why?

Comment: If it is the same queue then it will be block by dispatch_group_wait so your dispatch_group_leave never get a chance to execute.

Comment: That is correct; but in that case the result would be a deadlock. I don't have a deadlock. I have a crash after the execution continues because  dispatch_group_wait() reached the timeout. Also, even on the iOS8 device usually leave in both path is called. My problem occurs only if I do not call leave tow times. So it seems not to be the problem.

Comment: Have you looked into calling `dispatch_group_leave` when `finalValue` is false? Maybe you hit the assert [DISPATCH_CLIENT_CRASH("Semaphore/group object deallocated while in use");](https://opensource.apple.com/source/libdispatch/libdispatch-442.1.4/src/semaphore.c)

Comment: On iOS9 it always works regardless if I call both 'dispatch_group_leave()' times or run into the timeout. On iOS8 it works if both asyncOperation call 'dispatch_group_leave()' within 60 sec. If that happens the app works fine - if not, I get a crash after the return statement when I step out of the method.

Comment: Can you try setting finalValue to false when you return ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with this workaround:

```
private let MAX_TRIES = 20;

func dispatch_group_wait_ios8Safe(group: dispatch_group_t, _ timeout: dispatch_time_t) -> Int {

    if #available(iOS 9, *) {
        /* Just forward the call. */
        return dispatch_group_wait(group, timeout)
    } else {
        /* Forward the call to original function and store result. */
        let firstResult = dispatch_group_wait(group, timeout)
        var result = firstResult, tries = 0
        while(result > 0 && tries < MAX_TRIES) {
            dispatch_group_leave(group)
            result = dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_NOW)
            tries += 1
        }

        /* Return original result. */
        return firstResult
    }
}
```

So until someone comes up with a better solution I stick with this.